# alexa giving correct output only once and then says "Response is invalid"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am doing firebase and alexa integration in a way that the user will ask about a particular user location , alexa will store that user and compare it with firebase user. If user matches it will go to LocationData for particular match and fetches the latitude and longitude from there and replies "UserName location is *******". I have my function for this written in nodejs:

```
                            'use strict';
                var firebase = require('firebase');


               var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');

                    var options = {
                      provider: 'google',

                      // Optional depending on the providers 
                      httpAdapter: 'https', // Default 
                      apiKey: 'AIzaSyAzXrVTbsfiBK19SxvJP5b8pJErfhKahcw ', // for Mapquest, OpenCage, Google Premier 
                      formatter: null         // 'gpx', 'string', ... 
                    };

                    var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);



                /**
                 * This sample demonstrates a simple skill built with the Amazon Alexa Skills Kit.
                 * The Intent Schema, Custom Slots, and Sample Utterances for this skill, as well as
                 * testing instructions are located at http://amzn.to/1LzFrj6
                 *
                 * For additional samples, visit the Alexa Skills Kit Getting Started guide at
                 * http://amzn.to/1LGWsLG
              */
 if(firebase.apps.length == 0) {
      firebase.initializeApp({
        serviceAccount: "************",
        databaseURL: "****************"
        });
        }               
function getLocationFromSession(intent, session, callback)
{   
    const FirstNameSlot = intent.slots.FName;
    const firstName = FirstNameSlot.value;
    const LastNameSlot = intent.slots.LName;
    const lastName = LastNameSlot.value;
    const fullName = firstName+" "+lastName;
    const FullName = fullName.toLowerCase(); 

        var rootRef2 = firebase.database().ref().child("ProfileData");

        rootRef2.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        var childKey = childSnapshot.val();
        var name = childKey.DisplayName.toLowerCase();
        var key = childSnapshot.key;

        if(name==FullName)
         {

            var query = firebase.database().ref('/LocationData').orderByKey().equalTo(key);

            query.on( 'value', data => {

                  data.forEach(userSnapshot => {
                  var user = userSnapshot.val();
                  var latitude = user.Latitude;
                  var longitude = user.Longitude;
                  console.log(latitude);
                  geocoder.reverse({lat: latitude, lon: longitude})
                  .then(function(res) {
                    const repromptText = null;
                    const sessionAttributes = {};
                    let shouldEndSession = true;
                    let speechOutput = FullName+" location is "+res[0]['formattedAddress'];
                    callback(sessionAttributes,buildSpeechletResponse(intent.name, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
                    firebase.database().goOffline();

                  }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);


                  });
              });
            });
           //  if ends here
          }                  

        });
     });
  }






                // --------------- Helpers that build all of the responses -----------------------
                function buildSpeechletResponse(title, output, repromptText, shouldEndSession) {
                    return {
                        outputSpeech: {
                            type: 'PlainText',
                            text: output,
                        },
                        card: {
                            type: 'Simple',
                            title: `SessionSpeechlet - ${title}`,
                            content: `SessionSpeechlet - ${output}`,
                        },
                        reprompt: {
                            outputSpeech: {
                                type: 'PlainText',
                                text: repromptText,
                            },
                        },
                        shouldEndSession,
                    };
                }

                function buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) {
                    return {
                        version: '1.0',
                        sessionAttributes,
                        response: speechletResponse,
                    };
                }


                // --------------- Functions that control the skill's behavior -----------------------

                function getWelcomeResponse(callback) {
                    // If we wanted to initialize the session to have some attributes we could add those here.

                    const sessionAttributes = {};
                    const cardTitle = 'Welcome';
                    const speechOutput = 'Welcome to the Alexa Skills Kit sample. ' +
                        "Please ask me location of a user by saying , for example whats alex location";
                    // If the user either does not reply to the welcome message or says something that is not
                    // understood, they will be prompted again with this text.
                    const repromptText = 'Please ask me location of a user by saying, ' +
                        "for example whats alex location";
                    const shouldEndSession = false;

                    callback(sessionAttributes,
                        buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession));
                }

                function handleSessionEndRequest(callback) {
                    const cardTitle = 'Session Ended';
                    const speechOutput = 'Thank you for trying the Alexa Skills Kit sample. Have a nice day!';
                    // Setting this to true ends the session and exits the skill.
                    const shouldEndSession = true;

                    callback({}, buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, null, shouldEndSession));
                }

                function createContactAttributes(contactInfo) {
                    return {
                        contactInfo,
                    };
                }

                /**
                 * Sets the contact in the session and prepares the speech to reply to the user.
                 */





                // --------------- Events -----------------------

                /**
                 * Called when the session starts.
                 */
                function onSessionStarted(sessionStartedRequest, session) {
                    console.log(`onSessionStarted requestId=${sessionStartedRequest.requestId}, sessionId=${session.sessionId}`);
                }

                /**
                 * Called when the user launches the skill without specifying what they want.
                 */
                function onLaunch(launchRequest, session, callback) {
                    console.log(`onLaunch requestId=${launchRequest.requestId}, sessionId=${session.sessionId}`);

                    // Dispatch to your skill's launch.
                    getWelcomeResponse(callback);
                }

                /**
                 * Called when the user specifies an intent for this skill.
                 */
                function onIntent(intentRequest, session, callback) {
                    console.log(`onIntent requestId=${intentRequest.requestId}, sessionId=${session.sessionId}`);

                    const intent = intentRequest.intent;
                    const intentName = intentRequest.intent.name;

                    // Dispatch to your skill's intent handlers
                    if (intentName === 'MyContactIsIntent') {
                        setContactInSession(intent, session, callback);
                    } else if (intentName === 'WhatsMyLocationIntent') {
                        getLocationFromSession(intent, session, callback);
                    } else if (intentName === 'AMAZON.HelpIntent') {
                        getWelcomeResponse(callback);
                    } else if (intentName === 'AMAZON.StopIntent' || intentName === 'AMAZON.CancelIntent') {
                        handleSessionEndRequest(callback);
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Invalid intent');
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Called when the user ends the session.
                 * Is not called when the skill returns shouldEndSession=true.
                 */
                function onSessionEnded(sessionEndedRequest, session) {
                    console.log(`onSessionEnded requestId=${sessionEndedRequest.requestId}, sessionId=${session.sessionId}`);
                    // Add cleanup logic here
                }


                // --------------- Main handler -----------------------

                // Route the incoming request based on type (LaunchRequest, IntentRequest,
                // etc.) The JSON body of the request is provided in the event parameter.
                exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
                    try {
                        console.log(`event.session.application.applicationId=${event.session.application.applicationId}`);

                        /**
                         * Uncomment this if statement and populate with your skill's application ID to
                         * prevent someone else from configuring a skill that sends requests to this function.
                         */
                        /*
                        if (event.session.application.applicationId !== 'amzn1.echo-sdk-ams.app.[unique-value-here]') {
                             callback('Invalid Application ID');
                        }
                        */

                        if (event.session.new) {
                            onSessionStarted({ requestId: event.request.requestId }, event.session);
                        }

                        if (event.request.type === 'LaunchRequest') {
                            onLaunch(event.request,
                                event.session,
                                (sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) => {
                                    callback(null, buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                                });
                        } else if (event.request.type === 'IntentRequest') {
                            onIntent(event.request,
                                event.session,
                                (sessionAttributes, speechletResponse) => {
                                    callback(null, buildResponse(sessionAttributes, speechletResponse));
                                });
                        } else if (event.request.type === 'SessionEndedRequest') {
                            onSessionEnded(event.request, event.session);
                            callback();
                        }


                        } catch (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    }
                };
```

The only problem I am facing is about the output in alexa, first time when I ask about users location , it provides correct output , but as soon as I ask another users location , it says:

```
    response is invalid
```

In the log it says:

```
 START RequestId: fb182526-032b-11e7-b3ca-7556a3a89f6c Version: $LATEST
 2017-03-07T11:48:29.621Z   fb182526-032b-11e7-b3ca-7556a3a89f6c                          
 event.session.application.applicationId=amzn1.ask.skill.[unique-value-      
 here]2017-03-07T11:48:29.621Z  fb182526-032b-11e7-b3ca-7556a3a89f6c    
 onSessionStarted requestId=amzn1.echo-api.request.[unique-value-here], 
 sessionId=amzn1.echo-api.session.[unique-value-here]
 2017-03-07T11:48:29.637Z   fb182526-032b-11e7-b3ca-7556a3a89f6c    
 onLaunch requestId=amzn1.echo-api.request.[unique-value-here], 
 sessionId=amzn1.echo-api.session.[unique-value-here]
 END RequestId: fb182526-032b-11e7-b3ca-7556a3a89f6c
 REPORT RequestId: fb182526-032b-11e7-b3ca-7556a3a89f6c Duration: 18.36 
 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 34  
 MB
```

Can somebody help me with the code, can't figure it out whats wrong?

Comment: What's in the log?  What kind of object is in the variable `firebase` and where/when is it initialized?  The `.goOffline()` call could be leaving it in a state that it doesn't recover from during the next invocation due to the way (or placement/timing of) some earlier code -- not shown here -- is initializing it.  Is this a Lambda function, or where is it running?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes its a lambda function only.  You can view my whole code as I have edited in my question. So where to place .goOffline() function to get it working?

Comment: Look up "container reuse." Each time a Lambda function is invoked, it doesn't necessarilly start at the top. That only happens for certain the first time it runs.  The second invocation, and any after that, will start at `exports.handler()` -- leaving you with the firebase object offline.  The only time it starts at the top is (a) after several minutes pass with no invocations or (b) when the function is invoked while the function is already running and no idle containers are available or (c) at the next invocation after a code change.  Do you see why this is the explanation of your problem?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot So whats the appropriate solution that I can apply? Do you mean to say I should keep the code in export handler then?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the best practice for firebase.  It may be that you can completely avoid calling `goOffline` and instead set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = true;` to actually just leave it connected.  Moving everything inside the handler will reinitialize it every time, meaning longer runtimes.  Changing the context setting allows lambda to freeze the container after you call the final callback, and thaw it for the next request, even though that connection is still open.  Try that?

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot but setting context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; helped.